# Add an object of unknown class to ArrayList with reflection

Tags: java, arraylist, reflection

So I have an ArrayList of objects of unknown type extending Entity (my own class; not to be confused java.swing.text.html.parser.Entity) for reasons unrelated to this problem.

```
private ArrayList<? extends Entity> listedEntities = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is in a class that in its constructor receives a String and assigns it to the field entityClass.

At some point I am executing the following piece of code:

```
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(this.entityClass);
    Object newEntity = clazz.newInstance();

    listedEntities.add(newEntity);
```

Naturally, this doesn't work as the ArrayList is expecting an object of a class extending Entity and newEntity is of Object. So first thing was to try casting.

```
listedEntities.add(Class.forName(this.entityClass).cast(newEntity));
```

Also doesn't work. And after a few minutes not finding an answer I am here typing this.

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method add(capture#8-of ? extends Entity) in the type ArrayList<capture#8-of ? extends Entity> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#9-of ?)
```

Comment: How about forgetting about `?` and use some `T`

Comment: Is there a good reason that you are using `String` for `entityClass` instead of a `Class`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is like this:

- Change `listedEntities` to `ArrayList<Entity>` instead of `ArrayList<? extends Entity>`. It doesn't look like you have a particular reason to use the wildcard and the wildcard prohibits you from adding to the list.
- Change your construction to this:

  ```
  Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(this.entityClass);
  Entity newEntity = (Entity) clazz.newInstance();

  listedEntities.add(newEntity);
  ```

This will solve the compilation error and it's type-safe in that the explicit cast will throw an exception if somehow `this.entityClass` is not some subtype of `Entity`.

A fully-generic version as I believe @RC. hints at in the comments would be like this:

```
class Example<E extends Entity> {
    private List<E> listedEntities = new ArrayList<>();
    private Class<E> entityClass;

    Example(Class<E> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    void method()
    throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        E newEntity = entityClass.newInstance();
        listedEntities.add(newEntity);
    }
}
```

That is more 'proper'; however, whether you can use something like it or not depends on your specific needs.

---

As a side note, the fact that your error is thrown as an exception worries me a little bit. You should use a proper IDE which will flag compilation errors like that in the editor so you don't have to run the program to find them.

Comment: Regarding the side note: I'm using Eclipse Neon 2.0 but the exception is an exception due to having the following  entry point - public static void main(String[] args) { SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { new Primary(); }}); }

Comment: Well that seems fine. I think it should still flag the error during compilation but unfortunately I don't know enough about Eclipse to say why it might not in this case.

Comment: Regarding the proposed solution: It doesn't fulfil my needs to use an ArrayList<Entity>. Actually that was the initial version before using reflection at all. I need to have objects of the same class and that class needs to extend Entity. The fully generic version also doesn't do me good for one reason: The class I am in is defined as Lister<E> and it never is the same as the class the ArrayList holds.

Comment: If you've lost the type of the list you assign to `listedEntities`, you could convert it to `ArrayList<Entity>` by copying it e.g. `listedEntities = new ArrayList<Entity>(theSourceList)`. For the generic version, unless I'm misunderstanding, you could just add a second type variable like `Entity<E, T extends Entity>`. It's a bit hard to offer a better suggestion without knowing more about those restrictions. I already emphasized this briefly, but the wildcard will simply have to go if you want to add to `listedEntities`. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2891664.

Comment: It's a great clarification though. I'll have to move a lot of functionality down to a new class so I can go with the fully-generic version,  but your answer is indeed helpful and I am marking it as accepted.

Comment: No, of course, I could add a second type variable, but the thing is at the moment of initialisation of the variable of class Lister I still don't know the class extending Entity that will be required. As I said, your answer was helpful and it pushed me towards resolving the problem. Thanks.